# Adding the single string quote for value inside variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a variable, before I use that variable,I need to add string quotes to the value/data which is inside the variable using JavaScript need help

```
 //i am getting like this //
    var variable=king;

//i want to convert it with single quote//
     variable=variable;
```

but i need the data inside variable should be in a single quotation.

Comment: How and from where do you retrieve the value `king`, Can you enclose it with `''` there itself?\

Comment: assuming the variable contains string, you can concatenate it using quotes: var variable = "'"+king+"'"; (note the single quotes between doubles)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for . if you are not sure then parse it. variable.toString(). and if you want string quote you can do it. variable = '/''+ variable + '/'';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the variable with your quotes like :

```
function addQuotes(value){
    var quotedVar = "\'" + value + "\'";
    return quotedVar;
}
```

And use it like :

```
var king = addQuotes('king');
```

console.log will display :

```
'king'
```

Edit : you can try it in the chrome/firefox console, I did it and it works perfectly when copy/paste from here.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 'abc';
```

var sData = "\'" + x +"\'";

// sData will print "'abc'"

Answer (score 1):

var x = 'pqr';
var sData = "\'" + x +"\'";

// sData will print "'abc'"

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use doublequotes

```
var variable = "'" + variable + "'";
```

2) ... or You can escape single quote symbol with backslash

```
var variable = '\'' + variable + '\'';
```

Comment: @thanks ,but i have edit my question lit bit now,i want the variable value should  be in single quote.