# Adding single to javascript line added by ajax

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass javascript variables to the code added by ajax.

This is the line an struggling with:

```
onclick="fbShare('+url+','+value.title+')"
```

I want to achieve something like this `onclick="fbShare('https:myurlcom','This is a title.')`

I tried doing `onclick="fbShare("'+url+'","'+value.title+'")`

It gives `onclick="fbShare("https: myurl.com","This is a title.")`

And if I try to do `fbShare(url, value.title)` it says fbShare is not defined.

Comment: onclick="fbShare("+url+","+value.title+")" shoud works

Comment: You *need* not to use inline event handlers and use "proper" techniques instead such as `addEventListener`.

Comment: @KayisRahman Thanks, but it did not work.

Comment: @KayisRahman - no that won't work, it will result in the parameters not being strings.  It should be `onclick="fbShare('"+url+"','"+value.title+"')"`.  However, that is a quick fix for what should be written correctly, as @Niet says

Comment: As per @Niet suggetion. You can fix it like below.
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", fbShare(url,value.title));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me. This function `fbShare` has been used in multiple places so I tried finding solution to my problem instead of adding event handles.

This solution on Stack Overflow helped me [Adding the single string quote for value inside variable using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145281/adding-the-single-string-quote-for-value-inside-variable-using-javascript/39210303)